# Resolving "Module not found: Can't resolve" error when path is correct

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, clerk

I ran into a "Module not found: Can't resolve" error even though the path that I am trying to import is correct. Would you please help take a look and suggest how I can resolve this. The error I am getting is:

```
> nextjs@0.1.0 build
> next build

- info Loaded env from /Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/.env
- warn Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
- warn     The root value has an unexpected property, babel, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, configOrigin, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactProductionProfiling, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, target, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
- warn See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
- info Linting and checking validity of types ..- error ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from. Referenced from: /Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/.eslintrc.json
- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
- info Using external babel configuration from /Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/.babelrc
- warn It looks like there is a custom Babel configuration can be removed .
Failed to compile.

./pages/api/webhooks/user/chatbot-opened.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../../subFolder/utils/OpenAIStream'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

./middleware.ts
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/middleware.ts.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
    at successLoader (/Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
    at Object.loader (/Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

The path to the file where "OpenAIStream" is imported from is located at: `/Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/frontend/pages/api/webhooks/user/chatbot-opened.js` and the path to the "OpenAIStream" file is : `/Users/admin/Desktop/MainFolder/subFolder/forgedMartchatbot/utils`

`eslint.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals", "next"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

P.S: I tried asking AI models for answers, and didn't get any resolution.

Comment: ../../../../../subFolder/utils/OpenAIStream is your path ? try with ../../../../../subFolder/forgedMartchatbot/utils/OpenAIStream